# Common architecture of smart contract with one-to-many object relationship

Tags: solidity

I am writing smart contract with simple one-to-many relationship of two objects: Routes and Tickets. I plan to be able to sell and store sold tickets for routes.

My contract which I am still trying to write is here: https://gist.github.com/stashub1/4ed44d23d205501eda6c4c0583ccbc79

I used structure that [Rob Hitchens](https://medium.com/robhitchens/enforcing-referential-integrity-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-a9ab1427ff42) offered

In fact it is super hard to eve write such contract which seems super simple in terms of logic. To read it for someone else is even harder. Question is, is there any other pattern for such one-to-many structures? Maybe I am missing something and there is easier way to write such things?

Comment: Unfortunately the EVM isn't very good for handling large amounts of data. You don't have much choice it is either mapping or array, or a combination of both.

Comment: In the contract I'd use bytes32 instead of strings as keys to the routes mapping, using string costs more gas than bytes32.